# Allowing secure downloads in PHP for websites

Tags: php, security, download, zip, fileshare

I have uploaded some zip files to my server and now want to allow a user to download them if he/she has an appropriate password. I'm coding in PHP and I've made it so a user cannot access the page with the links to zip files unless the proper password has been entered, but by having a link to my zip file the user could just see and in future cases type in the absolute location of the zip file and bypass my password checks. If I change the file permissions on the zip file then I can't have it as a link because the user won't be able to access it. How can I allow the user to get the zip file while still keeping it secure? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to `mask url`.

- user logins
- generate a token based on his login details. some `md5` or whatever you decide
- create a download link (eg: `download.php`) that load the file based on valid token and session and get's the file with `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess to deny direct access to files. Put this .htaccess file in relevant folder.

Then from php authenticate user and after successful authentication, redirect user to a download.php with file name as a parameter (or even id), then use `force download` to let them download. This way even if they have direct link to zip file, they will not be able to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code that can hide download links/ the links need to expire and new links should take its place and/or links should change.

You can code it in PHP or use an existing piece of code that exactly does this.

http://sixthlife.net/product/secure-download-links/